# Metal 2 Multi Indirect Draw

Tags: graphics, 3d, game-engine, metal

Is there a way based on Metal 2 to do "Multi Indirect Draw" like "Direct X" 12 API "ExecuteIndirect"? Metal 2 has got some API to do single indirect draw, but multi indirect draw seems could not be found.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `MTLIndirectCommandBuffer` to encode draw or dispatch commands either on CPU or on GPU.

You create an `MTLIndirectCommandBuffer` with an `MTLIndirectCommandBufferDescriptor` that has a max number of commands set, as well as types of commands and other properties, such as pipeline and buffer bindings inheritance. Keep in mind, that you can't mix and match commands of different "stages". Meaning, you can have two different types of render commands, but you can't have both render and compute commands in the same buffer.

After that, you have two ways to encode it.

First is doing it on CPU. You can request an `MTLIndirectRenderCommand` object from the ICB with an `indirectRenderCommandAtIndex:` call or a compute one, `MTLIndirectComputeCommand` with an `indirectComputeCommandAtIndex:` call. It's kinda like a command encoder, but for a single command.

Second way is doing it on a GPU. You can pass the indirect command buffer into a shader by using argument buffers. You would use an `MTLArgumentEncoder`s `setIndirectCommandBuffer:atIndex:` method to write it there. After that, you can use an API similar to a CPU side API. You create a `render_command` or a `compute_command` from an index and `command_buffer` object that you have in your argument buffer in your shaders. This `command` struct has a bunch of methods to set buffers, pipeline states and encode draw or compute commands. You'd then dispatch a kernel with some threads that will use their position in grid to calculate an index into a command buffer and encode a command there.

Even though indirect commands look kinda like command encoders, it's good to keep in mind that a single command at an index only holds one actual command, so in a contrast from an encoder, any changes you make to the draw or compute command overwrite what was there previously.

After you have the commands encoded either on CPU or a GPU, you have to execute it. Depending on which types of command you have, you are going to call `executeCommandsInBuffer:indirectBuffer:indirectBufferOffset:` on either `MTLRenderCommandEncoder` or `MTLComputeCommandEncoder`.

That should cover the basics. For a more in-depth look, there are these two articles: [Encoding Indirect Command Buffers on the CPU](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/metal/indirect_command_buffers/encoding_indirect_command_buffers_on_the_cpu)
 and [Encoding Indirect Command Buffers on the GPU](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/metal/indirect_command_buffers/encoding_indirect_command_buffers_on_the_gpu)
, as well as this [Modern Rendering with Metal Sample](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/metal/modern_rendering_with_metal) that uses those ICBs quite heavily.

Comment: Thank you. May be I did not specify clearly, what I want is: for example, there are one sphere and one cube, I could just call DX 12 API ExecuteIndirect once to render the two objects on Windows platform. Now is it possible to call some API to do the same thing on iOS platform?

Comment: That is, drawing the sphere and cube with only one draw call.

Comment: You encode the indirect command buffer and then call `executeCommandsInBuffer`. This is the same concept.

Comment: My understanding(not sure right or not): In the indirect command buffer, one command for sphere, one command for cube, so actually executeCommandsInBuffer executes two commands, two draw calls.

Comment: How do you understand the ExecuteIndirect then?

Comment: For ExecuteIndirect , it may go like that: CPU calls it once, sends data to GPU, then GPU draw the two objects in two separate commands. One draw call on CPU, two draw steps on GPU. I read a technical article published in Chinese, it shows one draw call to draw two different objects, reference link: https://zhuanlan.zhihu.com/p/97671775

Comment: It's the same with indirect command buffers. You encode multiple commands into a buffer, that can get executed one or multiple times on a GPU. It doesn't really matter how the API looks, but in the end you get a GPU-visible buffer with data (in `ExecuteIndirect` and `MTLIndirectCommandBuffer` cases), the data just isn't exposed directly as bytes in Metal case. Then you can tell the GPU to execute that data indirectly, because you don't know ahead of time how many commands are gonna be there or what the commands are gonna be.

Comment: I also read this article, you may take a look then. Link: https://tellusim.com/metal-mdi/

Comment: I’ve seen that article. I mean, yeah, what he mentions is the most flexible thing you can have with metal